# Read SOAP result using a loop

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap

I built a web service in C# web application. I'm returning list of objects as a web service result. I need to know how to read that list of items one by one in a loop.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">  
  <soap:Body>  
    <checkAvailabilityResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">  
      <checkAvailabilityResult>  
        <Shedule>  
          <Sid>int</Sid>  
          <Fid>int</Fid>  
          <FromLocation>string</FromLocation>  
          <FromTime>dateTime</FromTime>  
          <ToLocation>string</ToLocation>  
          <ToTime>dateTime</ToTime>  
          <PriceSeatA>double</PriceSeatA>  
          <PriceSeatB>double</PriceSeatB>  
          <PriceSeatC>double</PriceSeatC>  
        </Shedule>  
        <Shedule>  
          <Sid>int</Sid>  
          <Fid>int</Fid>  
          <FromLocation>string</FromLocation>  
          <FromTime>dateTime</FromTime>  
          <ToLocation>string</ToLocation>  
          <ToTime>dateTime</ToTime>  
          <PriceSeatA>double</PriceSeatA>  
          <PriceSeatB>double</PriceSeatB>  
          <PriceSeatC>double</PriceSeatC>  
        </Shedule>  
      </checkAvailabilityResult>  
    </checkAvailabilityResponse>  
  </soap:Body>  
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is the way I tried:

```
SriLankanWebService.Service1SoapClient air1 = new AgentPortal.SriLankanWebService.Service1SoapClient();  
                List<Shedule> air1Response = (List<Shedule>)air1.checkAvailability(drpFrom.SelectedValue.ToString(), drpTo.SelectedValue.ToString(), DateTime.Parse(txtDepartOn.Text));
```

When I tried it says:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'AgentPortal.SriLankanWebService.Shedule[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AgentPortal.Shedule>'    D:\DCBSD\AgentPortal\AgentPortal\Home.aspx.cs   32  46  AgentPortal
```

I need to use it in a loop.

Comment: provide what kind of error/issue are you having. what help you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your code in last line from above code from:

```
 List<Shedule> air1Response = (List<Shedule>)air1.checkAvailability(drpFrom.SelectedValue.ToString(), drpTo.SelectedValue.ToString(), DateTime.Parse(txtDepartOn.Text));
```

to

```
AgentPortal.SriLankanWebService.Shedule[] = air1.checkAvailability(drpFrom.SelectedValue.ToString(), drpTo.SelectedValue.ToString(), DateTime.Parse(txtDepartOn.Text));
```

That will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, But it says  Error 2 Identifier expected D:\DCBSD\AgentPortal\AgentPortal\Home.aspx.cs 33 59 AgentPortal

Comment: check return type of air1.checkAvailability and update the Schedule array type